# How can i increase height of my content view without messing with message button?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

How can i make my view long? i want that the content view increases its height till the Message button
So how can i do that? you can see the image how its currenlty looking i tried to increase  paddingVertical but than message button is also going down side and not even visible, i want that view make its height still the message button without messing with message button how to do that?

[image]

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { formHead } from '../CommonCss/FormCss'


const GetUser = () => {

  const data = [
    {
      username: 'hello',
      image: 'img',
    }
  ]
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}> 
      <Image source={{ uri: data[0].image }} style={styles.userimg} />
      <Text style={styles.namesty}>{data[0].username}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.formbtn}>Message</Text>
      <Text style={styles.formbtn2}>Message</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default GetUser

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  formbtn: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    top: '50%',
    marginLeft: 35
  },
  formbtn2: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    top: '30%',
    marginLeft: 35
  },
  namesty: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#111111',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  userimg: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 75,
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: '#111111',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```

Comment: set the buttons inside another view and try to give the margin to that view

Answer (score 0):

In content and container style add flex:1

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}> 

      <ScrollView>
      <Image source={{ uri: data[0].image }} style={styles.userimg} />
      <Text style={styles.namesty}>{data[0].username}</Text>
      </ScrollView>

      </View>

     <View>
      <Text style={styles.formbtn}>Message</Text>
      <Text style={styles.formbtn2}>Message</Text>
     </View>

    </View>
  )

content: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: '#111111',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
```

Comment: not working its removing message button

Comment: See updated code above.

Comment: its working but the button is coming over the content i want that there should be a gap between button and content a little gap

Comment: That is due to your content is maybe large, you can use scrollview for content.

Comment: is their any way to do that?

Comment: See the updated code, for the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you, update this stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  formbtn: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 50,
    paddingVertical: 10,    
    fontWeight: "bold",
    // top: '50%',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: 35,
    bottom: 15+50+15
  },
  formbtn2: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 50,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    // top: '30%',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: 35,
    bottom: 15
  },
  namesty: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#111111',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  userimg: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 75,
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: '#444',
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: height-50-50-15-15-15
  }
})
```